# Using (sub)struct located in other package in Datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I haven't been able to find any information related to this.. let's say you call an API and save the resulted json into a struct in package Foo, like this:

```
package foo

type FooData struct {
  A string `json:"c"`
  B int    `json:"c"`
  C int64  `json:"c"`
}
```

Then you have your own model package:

```
package bar

import (
  "github.com/bla/bla/foo"
)

type BarData struct {
  A float
  Foo foo.FooData
}
```

Is this possible? Is there anything negative about doing it this way? The reason is the structs are over a hundred lines, so I feel it would be wasteful to duplicate it.

Also, what if I only want to index in B? Then I can just change it to:

```
type FooData struct {
  A string `datastore:",noindex" `json:"c"`
  B int    `json:"c"`
  C int64  `datastore:",noindex" `json:"c"`
}
```

?

Edit: Just to make it clear, my intention is to save the BarData struct in Datastore

Comment: What on earth should be wrong with `Foo foo.FooData`? What did you try? What did not work out as expected?

Comment: oh no you again.. if you are referring to whether I tried to insert data into `Foo foo.FooData` then yes, I of course tried it, and yes, it works as expected.. but my question is specifically related to Datastore and whether there's anything negative about doing it this way, which is something I dont think I'll be able to test/figure out by myself, so I hoped a Go&Datastore expert would be able to share thoughts on this type of structure and whether there's negative about it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go Datastore package has some documentation relating to this - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#hdr-Structured_Properties

"Structured Properties

If the struct pointed to contains other structs, then the nested or embedded structs are flattened. For example, given these definitions:

```
type Inner1 struct {
    W int32
    X string
}
type Inner2 struct {
    Y float64
}
type Inner3 struct {
    Z bool
}
type Outer struct {
    A int16
    I []Inner1
    J Inner2
    Inner3
}
```

then an Outer's properties would be equivalent to those of:

```
type OuterEquivalent struct {
    A     int16
    IDotW []int32  `datastore:"I.W"`
    IDotX []string `datastore:"I.X"`
    JDotY float64  `datastore:"J.Y"`
    Z     bool
}
```

If Outer's embedded Inner3 field was tagged as `datastore:"Foo"` then the equivalent field would instead be: FooDotZ bool `datastore:"Foo.Z"`.

If an outer struct is tagged "noindex" then all of its implicit flattened fields are effectively "noindex"."

So there shouldn't be any issues with you storing nested structs, just be aware that they will be flattened in datastore. It also mentions the no indexing, saying any field inherits a "noindex" from its parent struct. I don't see why your "noindex" tagging of the inner fields wouldn't work.

Comment: Does that mean it's no problem to point to structs in different packages, and include those `datastore:",noindex"` tags in any of the structs? I feel the documentation does not clarify this anywhere - I have seen several people on GitHub use `datastore:",noindex"` and similar tags on their sub/nested structs, but I cant seem to find any info (or any big projects) where they reference structs in other packages for their datastore data.

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why the package of the struct would have an effect on it.